# Regular expression using Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

Using `xpath 1.0`

```
html/body/form/div[6]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1];
```

in this    `tr[4]` and `td[1]` is changing

```
html/body/form/div[6]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/a;
```

in this   `tr[4]` and `td[1]` is changing

```
 html/body/form/div[6]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[3];
```

in this    `tr[4]` and `td[1]` is changing

can any body please help how to implement regular expression 
Thanks in advance

Comment: insert some html code that we can figure out the elements.

Comment: if you want to identify some elements on page you'd better simplify your xpath- don't use full path to element, but tags, class names, IDs, text... and why you need to implement `re`? what is the point?

Comment: there is nothing we can do if you don't share the html elements that you are attempting to interact with.  if you do edit your question to include this, please also include the parent, and some other ancestors. (for context)

Comment: with out absolute path

Comment: .//*[@id='ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ChildContent1_dgList']/tbody/tr[151]/td[1]

Comment: The place of the link in the table changes so the 151  changes ,  I want to identify the link by name because that is how i want to click on the link by name ,  could you please help me